# How to calculate run capacitor value for inductive motor?

Tags: stepper-motor

[image]

Hi.

At the attached circuit diagram you can see the connection of inductive motor (2 coils) with a capacitor and 12VAC source.
I would like to know how should I calculate the right value of the C1 capacitor in order to achieved a 90° shift in the capacitor-coil branch, so the motor will spin well? (according to the spec. that I drew on the diagram).

Thanks.